# StripTags and MysqlRealEscape an array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, strip-tags

I want to strip HTML code from multiple fields. So I used:

`extract($_POST)`

Then an insertion into the table.

I won't strip each field like:

```
$user  = strip_tags($user);
$email = strip_tags($email);
.....
```

There is any solution to strip my extract($_POST) array?

The same for mysql_real_escape_string()

**EDIT 1**
I won"t use

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
  $_POST[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($value));
}
```

I want to use the short variable:

```
$name, $email
```

not:

```
$_POST['name'] , $_POST['email']
```

And without extract() as is deprecated.

**Edit 2** the solution is:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
  $$key = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($value));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want this piece of code

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
   $$key = strip_tags($value);
}

//The insertion here
insertion();
```

Old

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
   $_POST[$key] = strip_tags($value);
   }

extract($_POST);

//The insertion here
insertion();
```

After that you have all the post fields strip_tagged

Comment: @raultm I won't use foreach because I'll do an insertion

Comment: ?? I don't understand what is  the problem, if you do the foreach before the extract you will have the same result but the $values will be strip tagged. I just notice that you're MiniNaim, you have a lot of work today. Enjoy the weekend! :)

Comment: @raultm I mean I want to use $name , $email ... not $_POST['name'], $_POST['email'] ...

Comment: with this foreach you will replace all the values(using the same key) of the $_POST array

Comment: @raultm Also I wont use extract() as is deprecated :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`array_map()`](https://www.php.net/array_map) to specify a callback function to each element of a given array.

`$_POST = array_map("strip_tags", $_POST`);

**Edit:** Maybe you should specify why you're attempting to escape user input. For example, PHP has specific aids for escaping values that will be added to the database and also for values that will be displayed on the page. As the former could result in an SQL injection and the latter an XSS vulnerability.

Comment: Can't get the values of the fields. Ann even wight `array_map('strip_tags', extract($_POST));` Still not escaping the HTML code

Comment: @MiniNaim: `extract()` won't work as it does not return an array. Also, it's probably not the best idea to rely on `extract()` on untrusted data as it relies on `register_globals` which is now deprecated .

Answer (score 1):

Use the [filtering functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php) that PHP provides, specifically in this case you would be interested in [`filter_input_array`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php):

```
$filtered = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRIPPED);
```

Comment: And by the way I want to remove html code from the value (not filtering it)